# List of all elements of $A_4$ - Jamie Mulholland p. 85

Tags: group-theory, permutations

> p. 72: $m$-cycle $\iff m - 1$ transpositions. Hence 3-cycle $\iff 2$ transpositions.
>   [image]

I condone all the calculations overhead, but I don't understand the proof blueprint.

(1.) How do you envisage and envision to list all elements with cycles of length $\le 2$ and 3-cycles?  Why not list other things? How do you know this is enough? I know $|A_4| = 4!/2 = 12$.

(2.) How do you craftily, indefectibly list all the 3-cycles ?
I keep fretting about if I missed something or listed the same thing more than once.

Answer (score 1):

$A_4$ is a subset of $S_4$. There are only 5 kinds of element in $S_4$: $(),(xx),(xxx),(xxxx),(xx)(xx)$. $A_4$ is the even permutations, $(),(xxx),(xx)(xx)$ --- the others are all odd permutations.

A 3-cycle fixes one number.

If it fixes the number $1$, then it must be $(234)$ or $(432)$.

If it fixes the number $2$, then it must be $(134)$ or $(431)$.

And so on.

If there's anything needing clarification, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

A permutation $\in S_n$ is even iff its cycle decomposition contains an even number of 2-, 4-, 6- etc. cycles (because these are odd) whereas the number of 1-, 3-, 5-, etc. cycles doesn't matter (because thy are even by themselves.

So for $n=4$ we have

- no 2-cycles and no other cycles (i.e. otherwise only 1-cycles): $e$
- no 2-cycles and one 3-cycle: The eight 3-cycles from above
- no 2-cycles and a 5- or longer cyle: not applicable
- no 2-cycles and at least two 3- or longer cycles: not applicable
- two 2-cycles: The three elements listed above
- two 2-cycles and one or more 3- or longer cycle: not applicable here
- four or more 2-cycles and possibly more: not aplicable here

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm perplexed by your first paragraph. What does 'odd' mean in (because these are odd)? You wrote 'an even number' just before it. Can you please notify me in your answer, and not in comments? And how did you flesh out all these cases?